# Can't use sa_sigaction - "sigaction doens't have a field sa_sigaction"

Tags: c

Hey guys I am messing around with signals, and have a weird error:
I want to set a value to the member sa_sigaction but IDE and compiler seem to not find it..

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <bits/siginfo.h>

struct sigaction new_action;

void SIGUSR1_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context) {
 ......
}

memset(&new_action, '\0', sizeof(new_action));  //cleaning the memory
new_action.sa_sigaction = SIGUSR1_handler;    //setting the handler for the signal
new_action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
```

I only posted the relevant part of the code.
Can anybody help me out here?

EDIT: And how can I put something in the siginfo struct or context pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify your OS so I can't be sure, but I think the problem is that you're inadvertently requesting an ancient version of POSIX that lacks it via the following incorrect feature test macro usage:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
```

The `_POSIX_SOURCE` macro itself is deprecated; you should be using `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` and defining it to the version of the API you want. To ensure the availability of a working `sigaction`, you probably want:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

since it was (if I recall correctly) an XSI extension in earlier versions of the standard. Alternatively you might use:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 /* or 700 */
```

since the functionality you want was available as an XSI extension in Issue 6.